# Enforce tagging in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tags

Created an IAM policy that should restrict user to now to allow ec2 instance creation when tags value not met

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/shutdown": "true",
                    "aws:RequestTag/terminate": "true"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "shutdown",
                        "terminate"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

Please check with the policy simulator at https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#

With the following policy, I'm able to confirm that it works:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/terminate": "true",
                    "aws:RequestTag/shutdown": "true"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "terminate",
                        "shutdown"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Application",
                        "Environment"
                    ]
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Application": [
                        "app-01",
                        "app-02"
                    ],
                    "aws:RequestTag/Environment": [
                        "development",
                        "production"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```